# Javascript array Browse and compare

Tags: javascript

I need to browse and compare two array and get the following result : 
For example:

```
T = [5,10,15];
V = [15,50,30];
```

I need to return the following values:

```
V[0]-T[0] = 15-5 = 10
V[1]-T[0] = 50-5 = 45
V[2]-T[0] = 30-5 = 25
```

### The MAX of the three value = 45

```
V[0]-T[1] = 15-10 = 5
V[1]-T[1] = 50-10 = 40
V[2]-T[1] = 30-10 = 20
```

### The MAX of the three value = 40

```
V[0]-T[2] = 15-15 = 0
V[1]-T[2] = 50-15 = 35
V[2]-T[2] = 30-15 = 15
```

The MAX of the three value = 35

I tried to do it by myself using this code:

```js
var T = [5,10,15];
var V = [15,50,30];
var X;
for (var i = 0; i < T.length; ++i){
    for (var j = 0; j <  V.length; ++j)
 {
  X = V[j]-T[i];   
  console.log(V[j]-T[i]); 
 }
 if ((V[j]-T[i]) >= X)
 {
  X = V[j]-T[i];
  console.log(V[j]-T[i]);
 }
    else
    {
        console.log(X); 
 }    
 console.log('\n');
}
```

But i get the following result:

```
10
45
25
25
5
40
20
20
0
35
15
15
```

Comment: My code don't return what i want (it's returning each time the last value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map `t` and take the maximum value of the mapped values of the subtraction.

This proposal features [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for an array for taking it as parameters.

```js
var  t = [5, 10, 15],
     v = [15, 50, 30],
     max = t.map(tt => Math.max(...v.map(vv => vv - tt)));

console.log(max);
```

ES5

```js
var  t = [5, 10, 15],
     v = [15, 50, 30],
     i, j,
     max,
     result = [];

for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    max = v[0] - t[i];                    // take the first value of v
    for (j = 1; j < v.length; j++) {      // iterate from the second value of v
       max = Math.max(max, v[j] - t[i]);  // get max value
    }
    result.push(max);                     // store max
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: While this is a very elegant solution using alot of ES6 syntactical sugar, OP propbably will have alot of problems understanding what it's even doing. Please consider explaining your code when OP's code shows you that he's probably rather accustomed to ES5.

Comment: Can you please suggest another simple solution instead of @Nina Scholz solution ?